# Power BI Desktop - How to change data source?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-desktop

When I'm trying to change my existing data source (Microsoft Azure CosmosDB) to Blob Storage, the `Change source` is disabled. How do I workaround this?

I have gone through various questions but none of them were similar to mine.
Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Try to remove your actual data source and reconnect it with the correct setting.

Answer (score 6):

Workaround

- Click on edit queries
- Select the query
- Advanced Editor

You can change the datasource from here.

Then do apply , export if necessary

Answer (score 1):

Like @rinjan stated above go to the advanced editor on your table in the query editor. Then you will get something like this (This is an Excel connection):

```
let
Source = Folder.Files("J:\TestPath"),
#"J:\TestPath\Map1 xlsx" = Source{[#"Folder Path"="J:\TestPath\",Name="Map1.xlsx"]}[Content],
#"Imported Excel" = Excel.Workbook(#"J:\TestPath\Map1 xlsx"),
Map1_Sheet = #"Imported Excel"{[Item="Map1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
....and so on
```

Best way to go here is to copy paste the whole text into the text editor and chose the option replace all with the following line (for this example):

```
Old value: J:\TestPath
New value: J:\New\Path
```

If it is not working you have to inspect the lines of codes. Maybe you find the missing piece.

Comment: Thanks @Strawberryshrub, I checked that and no connection details are specified there, however I can see from the actual document, it's still referencing the old source...

Answer (score 1):

The first line of every table must be Source:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Why-can-t-I-change-the-Data-Source-in-Power-BI-disabled-button/ba-p/915365

Comment: I don't understand. Where in that link does it say that the first line must be "Source"?